# Is it possible to farm balthazar points in Guild Wars?

Tags: guild-wars

Is it possible to farm balthazar points in Guild Wars? How? With a PvP or PvE character? I also read there is a limit of 2000 blthazar points. What exactly is the scope of this limit? And what is the best methode to win balthazar points once this 2000 limit is reached?

Comment: Possible dupe, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20069/what-are-the-deferents-possibilities-to-win-balthazar-points-in-guild-wars

Comment: best way to farm != possibilities to gain

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Zaishen Elite and get a team of Trappers. Common builds and explainations can be found there: http://www.gwpvx.com/Build:Team_-_Balthazar_FFF_Zaishen_Trapper

But the cap is 6000 faction each day and every point gained from Zaishen Challange also counts against this cap!
AFAIK this is the fastest way to gain faction if you do NOT want to play straight PvP.

If you want more than these 6k/day just play Random Arena, Alliance Battles or Competitive Missions (Jade Quarry, Fort Aspenwood). With the corresponding Zaishen Battle quest a good amount can be gained.
See http://www.gwpvx.com/PvX_wiki for builds

Comment: This is the same response I put on the other question, so commenting that the questions are different and putting the same answers seems pointless.