# What different ways are there to win Balthazar faction points in Guild Wars?

Tags: guild-wars

What are the different ways (except farming) to win Balthazar faction points in Guild Wars? And what is the most efficient arena or fastest method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other ways of gaining balthazar faction:

1. Buy flames of Balthazar from people, each normal flame gives 1k points, each gold flame gives 3k.  I haven't checked the price on those in a while.
2. Do PvP, most forms of pvp allows you to gain balthazar faction points, doesn't matter what type.  The easiest type to start with is Random Arena and also the Kurzick/Luxon faction pvp battles (assuming you have the Factions Campaign)

Outside of those 2 methods and the hero arena farming method DavidYell mentioned, there is no other way to gain balthazar points.

As for the most efficient, it depends on if you are good at pvp or not.  The most time efficient way of gaining balthazar faction is waiting for a double weekend in some of the pvp arenas and participating, but unless you have high rank or experience in Halls or GvG, I'd stick to random arena and/or the faction arenas.

Comment: I checked the [Guild Wars Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Zaishen_Key). The normal [Flame of Balthazar](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Flame_of_Balthazar) cost two silver Zaishen coins (or 100 copper Zaishen coins). It is possible to win these copper coins with the [Zaishen quests](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Zaishen_Challenge_Quest). I think doing these Zaishen quest is more efficient to gain Balthazar faction points than doing PvP.

Comment: Zaishen quests are limited. They change each day, whereas gaining faction using PvP is unlimited uses per day as it were. The turnaround will be quicker and potentially easier.

Comment: For PvP it is also possible to take advantage of the Zaishen rewards to optimize Balthazar gain in Random Arena. [The Random Arena Zaishen quest](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Random_Arena_(Zaishen_quest)) gives 3000 balthazar points.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what '2000 point' method you are talking about, do share! :)

I use a PvP made Traps Ranger to farm Balthazar faction, using the 'Victory is Mine Trappers' opponents in the Ascalon arena. This allows me to get maximum faction each day in about 10-15 minutes.

The build I use revolves around Spike Trap.

I have a thread on our guild forums, which will be more informative. **Need to be registered, sorry**

> This is a straight forward build, which you can use to farm the max Balthazar Faction each day. You'll want to get 7,777 to unlock Thackery as a Hero, in case you didn't know they snuck in a new hero!  :roll:
>
> [Rng;OgATYx7iXa4q5Y5gLU5YXi465AA] - Link, http://gw.gamependium.com/tools/builds/template/?key=OgATYx7iXa4q5Y5gLU5YXi465AA
>
> Super Wilderness + Attunement runes and a +Energy staff, then just run the bar twice. Job done.
>
> I made a specific PvP Ranger for this, with 61 energy.
>
> Make sure you do the Heroe's Crypt against the 'Victory is Mine' Trapper team.

Comment: The 2000 points is the maximum you are talking about. I woulk like to know what are the OTHER and more CLASSIC possibilities to win balthazar point.